# Easy way to delete a table column from a web brower's web inspector?

Tags: html, html-table, web-inspector

I take a lot of screen shots of web pages for documentation and similar purposes. Often it is useful to delete or manipulate elements before taking the screen shot to hide stuff you don't want people to see, emphasize something, simplify the screen shot etc.

In <tables> it is easy to remove unwanted horizontal rows by deleting a <tr> node but what if you want to delete a vertical column? You can of course delete the nth <td> on every row in the table to delete the nth column but that is a PITA if the table is big. Is there some shortcut that allows me to delete a vertical column in a table as easy, or at least easier than deleting, one by one, all the <td> in that column, as it is to delete a table row?

I know HTML tables aren't spreadsheets but in most spreadsheet programs you can right click a column header and delete the column. A similar solution for HTML tables would be very nice to have!

Comment: If you have control over the code, you could label up all the TD tags that make up the column with a particular class, then hide using JS

Comment: @moo Unfortunately I don't have that type of access in most cases.